# How to remove the ' quote from string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string, quotes, fastercsv

I am trying to upload some data from my csv to the database using fastercsv. here is how my csv looks like:

```
'name';'number';'sub_category_id';'category_id';'quantity';'sku';'description';'cost_price';'selling_price'
'Uploaded Item Number 1';45;'KRT';'WN';56;'WNKRT0045';'Some Description';4566;6788
'Uploaded Item Number 2';56;'PNT';'MN';34;'MNPNT0056';'Some Description';5677;7655
```

I am getting the data the way I wanted but the strings are being formed like this: `:name => "'Uploaded Item Number 1'", :sub_category_id => "'KRT'"` .. So, when I save this data into items table the field which contain this data looks like this: **'Uploaded Item number 1'** in **name**, **'KRT'** in **sub_category_id** .. instead of simple **Uploaded Item Number 1** in **name** and **KRT** in **sub_category_id**. How this single quote (') can be removed from strings, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try within the `DEFAULT_OPTIONS` settings on fastercsv, change `:quote_char` to `'`

e.g.

```
FasterCSV.foreach(path_to_csv, :col_sep => ';', :quote_char => "'") do |row| 
  use row here.. 
end
```

See:

http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

Comment: +1, @trickwallett Thanks it worked, I did this: `FasterCSV.foreach(path_to_csv, :col_sep => ';', :quote_char => "'") do |row|  use row here..   end` and it gets me the string in same way I wanted. I would like you to edit your answer and paste the code written in this comment . So, I can mark it as accepted and in future if someone came across to such issue also can refer to this post. Thanks again!!